# How do I link (join) a sharepoint list and an external data source in a DVWP?

Tags: wss-3.0, data-view-web-part, sql-server, sharepoint-designer

I've got an external data source (SQL Server) and a Sharepoint Custom List that I want to join in a single view using the data view web part.

In theory this shouldn't be too hard, but I can't get it to work:

1) I created a linked source, using "Join" as the type.

2) I created a new DVWP, and then inserted a column from the first table as a Multiple Item View.

3) I then inserted a column from the second table as a "Joined Subview".

In the examples that I've seen online, at this point I'm supposed to be presented with a dialog that allows me to specify which columns in the two data sources are related.  However, I never receive any such dialog, the second column is simply inserted, and the same row data repeats for every row from first table.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk about FRUSTRATING.  The problem was simply that I only had one item in the Sharepoint list.  After adding a second item to the list, I received the join dialog that allowed me to specify which columns to join on.